# Refactoring condition more efficient

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements, refactoring, dry

I wrote a code with condition and for me I have lots a repetition of similar code.
Can I make this code more efficient with a refactor ?
After some research, that's the best that I can do
that's just a part of the code, not the entire
https://codepen.io/manofthelake/pen/GRyMzgW?editors=1010

```
  const firstNumber = 50
  const lastNumber = 1000
  const defaultMinNumber = firstNumber + Math.round((lastNumber - firstNumber) / 2 )
                                                       
  const selection = {
    min: null
    max: null
    }                                                     

  if (Object.values(selection).every(s => s === null)) {
    selection.min = defaultMinNumber
    selection.max = lastNumber
  }
  else if (selection.min < firstNumber) {
    savedSelection = {...selection}
    selection.min = (selection.max > firstNumber) ? firstNumber: defaultMinNumber
    selection.max = (selection.max > firstNumber) ? selection.max : lastNumber
  }
  else if (Object.values(savedSelection).every(s => s !== null)) {
    selection.min = (savedSelection.max > firstNumber) ? selection.min : defaultMinNumber
    selection.max = (savedSelection.max > firstNumber) ? selection.max : lastNumber
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Observations/Refactoring **:**

- What is the different between `lastNumber` and `defaultMinNumber` as both will return same value. Looks like something has been missed in that calculation.
- Instead of loop on each and every element you can use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

  ```
  selection.min ?? defaultMinNumber
  selection.max ?? lastNumber
  ```

Comment: - For the 1st point, I forgot a /2 in the code (I added it) so it return half

- For the 2nd point, I don't understand your answer, because it can't be null or undefined on this loop

Comment: 2nd point is to optimize the extra loop you are performing to assign the numbers if values are null. Hence, in that case nullish operator will be helpful.

Comment: Have you advice for the  else if statements ? IMO it can be simplify but how ?